# PowerShell date/time conversion

Tags: powershell

I have a variable, $date, containing `24 June 2012 00:00:00`.

How do I convert this to `24/06/2012`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `Get-Date` cmdlet together with the Format parameter:

```
PS> $date = '24 June 2012 00:00:00'
PS> Get-Date $date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy'
24/06/2012
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried reading a file with dates formatted day-month-year
The answer above did not work for me, I found a different solution on how to parse my dates and check which one is newer than the current date. This is my adapted code.

```
$currdateobj = Get-Date
$STARTDATE = "12-05-2017"    // specific non-default date format
[DateTime]$startdateobj = [DateTime]::ParseExact($STARTDATE,"dd-MM-yyyy",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
if ($startdateobj -lt $currdateobj)
{
   // ....
}
```