# convert Fri Nov 02 14:37:02 2018 to 2018-11-02 14:37:02

Tags: powershell, date, timestamp, logfile

I want to convert `Fri Nov 02 14:37:02 2018` to `2018-11-02 14:37:02` in Windows Powershell, thanks for any proposals.

Comment: Hi @jack. Can you please share your code. What did you try so far?

Comment: is the 1st a string or is it a datetime object? if it is the 2nd, then are you talking about _displaying_ the date in the logical yyyy-MM-dd format or doing something else?

Comment: its a string, i have this text in a log file

Comment: @jack - kool! see my answer below ... [*grin*]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell date/time conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314349/powershell-date-time-conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how to convert a time *string* to a datetime object & back again ... [*grin*]

```
$TimeString = 'Fri Nov 02 14:37:02 2018'
$TimeObject = Get-Date -Date '2018-11-02 14:37:02'

'String       = {0}' -f $TimeString
# convert the above string to a datetime object
$TS_DateTimeObject = [datetime]::ParseExact('Fri Nov 02 14:37:02 2018', 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy', $Null)

# my PC locale is set to use yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss as the datetime format
#    most stateside PC locale setting will be MM-dd-yyyy
'Object       = {0}' -f $TimeObject
'TS_Object    = {0}' -f $TS_DateTimeObject

# convert a datetime object to a string
'DT to String = {0}' -f $TimeObject.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

output ...

```
String       = Fri Nov 02 14:37:02 2018
Object       = 2018-11-02 2:37:02 PM
TS_Object    = 2018-11-02 2:37:02 PM
DT to String = 2018-11-02 14:37:02
```

---

here is a link to the datetime format codes ...

Date and Time formats - PowerShell - SS64.com
— https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-dateformats.html

Comment: i have this Fri Nov 02 14:37:02 2018 in input file and i want this 2018-11-02 14:37:02 in output file

Comment: @jack - so ... use the `ParseExact()` to convert to a datetime object & then the `.ToString()` method & date string formatting to give you a string in the desired format. [*grin*]